# MVC 4 How do I add a function with parameters in the OnSuccess callback of the Ajax.ActionLink helper?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am running into a several problems trying to add parameters to a function I'd like called when the OnSuccess method is fired after my ajax call.

Currently I have the following code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "isFormSuccessful('AddDomainNameForm','#ajaxModal',data)", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxTarget" }))
```

This produces no errors and the function does get called, but it does not get called at the proper time. It is being called before the response has been redrawn in the target div. When I investigate this issue, there are many articles which say that this is caused when one passes parameters in the function within the OnSuccessCallback. Those same articles suggest doing something like this:

```
OnSuccess = "function(){exampleFunction('" + param1 + "');}"
```

When I try that however jQuery 1.9.1 throws the following error:

> Function must have a name.

I'm wondering if this is a problem with the newer jQuery. The parameters I am passing are necessary because hey are not found in the data posted back from the server.

Any help on achieving this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the function anonymous:

```
OnSuccess = "(function(){exampleFunction('" + param1 + "');})();"
```

Comment: I apologize. I spoke too soon. It still seems to be executing this function before the server response is redrawn in the target div.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I am a complete nob and was not populating the extra parameters on the get half of the form draw. I apologize for wasting your time.